# Can't drop a user that is currently connected

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to reinitialize an Oracle DB and am seeing the following error:

```
  [sql] Failed to execute:  drop user conns cascade
  [sql] java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected
  [sql] Failed to execute:  create user conns identified by conns default tablespace tbs_conns temporary tablespace temp1
  [sql] java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01920: user name 'CONNS' conflicts with another user or role name
```

The problem is that **NO ONE** is connected: this is an instance on my local computer, no outside connections and I *just* rebooted and have not run anything else. The only thing I can think of is that Oracle might have some background (cleanup?) task running that is causing this issue, but I have no clue how to find/manage that. Any ideas?

**Update**: this script actually drops and reinitializes a bunch of tables, and after trying to re-run it a few times, I got the *same* error message but on a *different* table: `Failed to execute:  drop user csmy cascade`. After a few more tries, it moved onto yet *another* user: `Failed to execute:  drop user deb cascade`. Something seems to be locking these tables, one at a time, in alphabetical order!

**Update 2**: after re-running the script about 15 times - each time failing at a table slightly further along in the alphabet - it has gotten all the way through and things are working. I'd still love to know exactly what happened - my best guess is some background Oracle process, but I have no clue how to check.

**Update 3**: I ran into this same issue again the last time I re-ran the script, this time failing on user "cap". To try something new, I fired up sqlplus and manually ran the `drop user cap cascade` command and, lo and behold, it worked just fine. I tried the script and it ran to completion. Therefore, since manually dropping a user works w/o issues, I strongly suspect the script itself is to blame.

Comment: If the `drop user cap cascade` command works (presumably from sql*plus) and your script has problems, then it would be useful to see your script.

Answer (score 1):

Does the script use the same connection ? Is it trying top simultaneous drop multiple users ?

It looks like if it encounters an error, it simply continues to the next step.

There can be dependencies between objects in different schemas which may prevent an object in schema A being dropped until an object in schema B is dropped. As a result if may fail to drop schema A initially, but succeed on a retry if schema B has been dropped.

Comment: It always failed on trying to drop a user, so I don't see how dependencies would matter. It would also fail multiple times on the same user before randomly moving onto another one later in the alphabet. I'll look into the script to see what's happening with connections and if there are any simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 1):

Have you queried from v$session to see who is connected?  You might have an application running somewhere that re-connects automatically.  You can always start the database in restricted mode or don't start the listener and run your script from a local connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if all connections closed properly in case of exception.
2. Look at JDBC connection properties.
   If connection pooling or caching enabled some connections from previous run may still alive.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your script it's hard to tell exactly what happens. But I can assure you that the database itself never connects to specific users.

What you can do is let your code log on (I assume your code runs as a DBA user) and loop through all users you want to drop. For each, issue REVOKE CREATE SESSION FROM 
That disables login so any mysterious code will be unable to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, if you had tried a

```
ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION '<sid>,<serial#>' IMMEDIATE
```

(for each session of the user you try to drop) before dropping the user, it would have worked?

Just guesswork.